# How to pass variadic argumens to other functions

Tags: go

Is there any way the function Warn could be made to work?

```
func Warn(s string, args ...interface{}) {
    log.Printf("warn: "+s, args)
}

func main() {
    Warn("%d apples, %s ", 10, "good") //it should output the same as below
    log.Printf("%d apples, %s ", 10, "good")
}
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 warn: [10 %!d(string=good)] apples, %s(MISSING) 
2009/11/10 23:00:00 10 apples, good
```

I'm trying to make this work: http://play.golang.org/p/W62f2NGDUe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it:

```
func Warn(s string, args ...interface{}) {
    log.Printf("warn: "+s, args...)
}
```

Now it works.